# Solr json.facet range query with month grouping

Tags: solr

I have got a solr query (Solr version 6.0.2) which groups and sums sales per day. Everything works great with following parameters:

```
json.facet=sales:{
      type:range,
      field:date_add,
      start:'2016-05-31T22:00:00Z',
      end:'2016-10-31T22:59:59Z',
      gap:'+1DAY',
      facet:{
         ordersSum:'sum(sales_value)'
      }
   }
```

(The specified hour 22:00:00 in **start** parameter is because of time zone ,since Solr keeps dates in UTC and my application works in Europe/Warsaw time zone)

With that I've got nice sales values with respect to days specified between **start** and **end** parameters. However now I want to do the same, but for the month basis, so I want sales for june, july [..] october.

I've figured out that, It's possible to change gap parameter to **'+1MONTH'**, but the values are not consitent, since months aren't equal:

```
"val":"2016-05-31T22:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-06-30T22:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-07-30T22:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-08-30T22:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-09-30T22:00:00Z",
```

As it can be seen, the dates defaults to the first occured lower number of days (ie. july and agust have 31 days). Again the problem can be solved by manipulation of **start** parameter to:

```
2016-05-31T22:00:00Z/MONTH
```

The **/MONTH** suffix tells Solr to default to first day of month, at midnight. Then fetched dates looks good:

```
"val":"2016-06-01T00:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-07-01T00:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-08-01T00:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-09-01T00:00:00Z",
"val":"2016-10-01T00:00:00Z",
```

However given date values are correct for UTC time zone. Is there a way for Solr to add months properly, or set timezone for results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured it out. It's possible to set timezone globally for the Solr query by adding additional parameter to the query:

&TZ=Europe/Warsaw

In my case the results are following:

```
"val":"2015-08-31T22:00:00Z",
"val":"2015-09-30T22:00:00Z",
"val":"2015-10-31T23:00:00Z",
"val":"2015-11-30T23:00:00Z",
```

(I've changed **start** / **end** parameters a bit to show how daylight saving time is kept). Additionally, the **/MONTH** suffix is not needed in that case, it only helps to keep the starting time correct.